# Add new div with jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now I try to add new Div with this code  it's work.
The Problem is when I try to add new Div in a lasted row.
It's always after lasted row.
I need to add new Div next to the last row.

Maybe it's because of `insertAfter` but I can't fix it.

```
var math = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);  
var math2 = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);  

$(document).ready(function(){

     $('<div class="row mt-2"" id="rowExpression'+math+'"></div>').appendTo('#overall');
     $('<div class="col-md-9" id="Selector'+math+'"></div>').appendTo('#rowExpression'+math);
     $('<h5> e '+math+'</h5>').appendTo('#Selector'+math);
     $('<div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2" id="CRUDExpression'+math+'"></div>').appendTo('#rowExpression'+math);
     $('<i class="btn success-item fas fa-plus-circle pr-1" onclick="addRow(this)" id="'+math+'" ></i>').appendTo('#CRUDExpression'+math);
     $('<i class="btn cross-item fas fa-minus-circle pl-1" onclick="deleteRow(this)" id="'+math+'" ></i>').appendTo('#CRUDExpression'+math);


    }); 


function addRow(eId) {

     var mathX = Math.random().toString(36).substr(3, 12);

     $('#rowExpression'+eId.id).one( "click",function(){
         var x = $(this).prev().attr('id');

     console.log(x +'                neastest div');
     console.log(eId.id +'                    this id');
     console.log(mathX +'                     new id');

     var lastedId = $('.row').last().attr("id") ;
     console.log(lastedId, "rowExpression"+mathX);

     $('<div class="row mt-2"" id="rowExpression'+mathX+'"></div>').appendTo('#overall')
     .insertAfter($( "#"+x ));
     $('<div class="col-md-9" id="Selector'+mathX+'"></div>').appendTo('#rowExpression'+mathX);
     $('<h5> e '+mathX+'</h5>').appendTo('#Selector'+mathX);
     $('<div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2" id="CRUDExpression'+mathX+'"></div>').appendTo('#rowExpression'+mathX);
     $('<i class="btn success-item fas fa-plus-circle pr-1" onclick="addRow(this)" id="'+mathX+'" ></i>').appendTo('#CRUDExpression'+mathX);
     $('<i class="btn cross-item fas fa-minus-circle pl-1" onclick="deleteRow(this)" id="'+mathX+'" ></i>').appendTo('#CRUDExpression'+mathX);


}); 

}

function deleteRow(eId) {
    console.log(eId.id);
    $("#rowExpression"+eId.id).remove();    

}
```

[image]

This is my html.

```
<form action="#" method ="post">
<div id="overall" class="col-md-12">
</div>
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-2 mt-2" value="submit" >submit</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: please provide your html

Comment: I my html update now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I getting my answer with myself now.
Thank you all.

```
function addRow(eId) {

     var mathX = Math.random().toString(36).substr(3, 12);

     $('#rowExpression'+eId.id).one( "click",function(){
         var nearest = $(this).prev().attr('id');

     console.log(nearest +'                neastest div');
     console.log(eId.id +'                    this id');
     console.log(mathX +'                     new id');


     var lastedId = $('.row').last().attr("id") ;
     console.log(lastedId, "rowExpression"+mathX);

     /*$('<div class="row mt-2"" id="rowExpression'+mathX+'"></div>').appendTo('#overall')
     .insertAfter($( "#"+nearest ));*/

     if('rowExpression'+eId.id == lastedId) {
         $('<div class="row mt-2"" id="rowExpression'+mathX+'"></div>').appendTo('#overall');

         }
     else{
         $('<div class="row mt-2"" id="rowExpression'+mathX+'"></div>').appendTo('#overall')
         .insertAfter($( "#"+nearest ));

         }
     $('<div class="col-md-9" id="Selector'+mathX+'"></div>').appendTo('#rowExpression'+mathX);
     $('<h5> e '+mathX+'</h5>').appendTo('#Selector'+mathX);
     $('<div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2" id="CRUDExpression'+mathX+'"></div>').appendTo('#rowExpression'+mathX);
     $('<i class="btn success-item fas fa-plus-circle pr-1" onclick="addRow(this)" id="'+mathX+'" ></i>').appendTo('#CRUDExpression'+mathX);
     $('<i class="btn cross-item fas fa-minus-circle pl-1" onclick="deleteRow(this)" id="'+mathX+'" ></i>').appendTo('#CRUDExpression'+mathX);



}); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're using 'insertAfter()' instead you should use '.append()' cause this way you will add your new code after the last one.

Comment: If i use append() when i try to add between them. It's look sick

Answer (score 0):

Without your HTML is hard to guess (where are those classes and how you structured them. 
I will say try and use after instead of insertAfter, that could be the problem. 
http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

Comment: Hi @Ashaghel. Try to don't make answer if you are not sure about the question. Instead of that you can use comment behaviour to ask clarifications like html or clases.